# Prove that iff the vertices represent an equilateral triangle, then $a^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2-\alpha\beta - \gamma\alpha - \beta\gamma=0$

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

> Show that the distinct complex numbers $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ represent the vertices of an equilateral triangle (taken in any order) if and only if $$a^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2-\alpha\beta - \gamma\alpha - \beta\gamma=0$$

If $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ represent the vertices of a triangle, in anticlockwise order then $$(\gamma-\alpha)e^{-\frac{i\pi}{3}}=\beta-\alpha$$
$$(\alpha-\beta)e^{-i\frac{\pi}{3}} = \gamma-\beta$$
$$(\alpha-\gamma)e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}} = \beta-\gamma$$

Multiplying equation 1 and equation 3, then $$(\gamma-\alpha)(\alpha-\gamma)=(\beta-\alpha)(\beta-\gamma)$$
$$\alpha\gamma -\gamma^2 -\alpha^2+\alpha\gamma = \beta^2-\beta\gamma - \alpha\beta +\alpha\gamma$$

$$\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2-\alpha\beta-\beta\gamma-\alpha\gamma=0$$

To complete the iff $\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2-\alpha\beta-\beta\gamma-\alpha\gamma=0$ then we must show this expression implies we have an equilateral triangle.

$$\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2-\alpha\beta-\beta\gamma-\alpha\gamma=0\implies(\gamma-\alpha)(\alpha-\gamma)=(\beta-\alpha)(\beta-\gamma)\implies$$
$$|\gamma-\alpha||\alpha-\gamma|=|\beta-\alpha|\beta-\gamma|$$

$$|\alpha-\gamma|^2=|\beta-\alpha||\beta-\gamma|$$

As the quadratic expression above in $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ is cyclic then we can write similar expressions for all sides.

$$|\beta-\alpha|^2=|\gamma-\beta||\gamma-\alpha|$$

$$|\gamma-\beta|^2=|\alpha-\gamma||\alpha-\beta|$$

I don't know how to make my proof more obvious than this. But if the square of the sides of a triangle equals the product of the other two lengths, then surely the only way that could happen is if the lengths of the sides are equal?

The triangle that I am referring to in this problem:

> [image]

Comment: Also related: [Vertices of equilateral triangle on complex plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2782992/vertices-of-equilateral-triangle-on-complex-plane), and [Let $z_1$, $z_2$ and $z_3$ be complex vertices of an equilateral triangle. Show $z_1^2 + z_2^2 + z_3^2 = z_1 z_2 + z_2 z_3 + z_3 z_1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068254/let-z-1-z-2-and-z-3-be-complex-vertices-of-an-equilateral-triangle-show).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, to finish this argument off, you need to show that, if $a, b, c \ge 0$ such that $a^2 = bc$, $b^2 = ac$, and $c^2 = ab$, then $a = b = c$. A simple way to do this is to order these numbers from least to greatest, i.e. so that $a \le b \le c$, and observe that:
$$c = \sqrt{ab} \le \sqrt{b^2} = b \le c,$$
and similarly,
$$a = \sqrt{bc} \ge \sqrt{b^2} = b \ge a.$$

Comment: Oh, very nice method. Thank you for your assistance