# Conditions of equilateral triangle in complex plane/equivalence of angles between segments

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, analytic-geometry

Suppose that $z_1, z_2, z_3 \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $z_1^2 + z_2^2 + z_3^2 = z_1z_2 + z_1z_3 + z_2z_3$. In order to conclude that the triangle formed by $z_1, z_2, z_3$ is equilateral, it is sufficient to show that all angles of the triangle are equal. In ProofWiki this is done by showing that $\frac{z_2 - z_1}{z_3 - z_2} = \frac{z_3 - z_1}{z_1 - z_2}$, after which the article concludes that: "Thus $z_2 - z_1$ and $z_3 - z_1$ are at the same angle to each other as $z_3 - z_2$ and $z_1 - z_2$". [Link to the article](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Vertices_of_Equilateral_Triangle_in_Complex_Plane).

What known theorem/property yields the result between the angles from the equality $\frac{z_2 - z_1}{z_3 - z_2} = \frac{z_3 - z_1}{z_1 - z_2}$? I have done barely any geometrical arguments for the past few years, so I am quite rusty with the machinery.

Comment: $\frac{z_2-z_1}{z_3-z_2}=-\frac{z_1-z_2}{z_3-z_2}=-a$. $|a|=\frac{|z_1-z_2|}{|z_3-z_2|}$ and $\arg a$ is angle of rotation from $z_3$ to $z_1$ with center in $z_2$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Could you further elaborate on this answer? I don't see how it establishes the claimed connection with $\frac{z_3 - z_1}{z_1 - z_2}$.

Comment: @EpsilonAway The wiki page explains that in the links to Complex Multiplication. If there is something in there which is not clear, you should ask about that specifically.

Comment: @dxiv Yeah, it just occurred to me why it holds true: If we just consider the arguments, then the fractions read as: "The difference between the arguments of $z_2 - z_1$ and $z_3 - z_2$ is equal to that of the difference between $z_3 - z_1$ and $z_1 - z_2$".

Comment: @EpsilonAway Right, that's all there is to it. About the problem itself, see also [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/953129/equilateral-triangle-from-three-complex-points), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068254/let-z-1-z-2-and-z-3-be-complex-vertices-of-an-equilateral-triangle-show), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102458/how-does-this-equality-on-vertices-in-the-complex-plane-imply-they-are-vertices).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The argument of a complex number is the counterclockwise angle made by the vector joining the point representing the complex number (in the Argand plane) to the origin, with the positive X axis.

 Any angle measured clockwise, starting from the positive direction of the X axis, is taken as negative by convention.

 More specifically, $arg(z_1-z_2)$ is the counterclockwise angle made by the vector joining the point representing $z_2$ to the point representing $z_1$, with the positive X axis. 
We must also note that the following property holds given that $z,\omega≠0:$
$$arg(\frac zω)=arg(z)-arg(\omega)$$

In the image, let $\alpha$ be divided into $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$.
Since $\theta_2$ is measured clockwise wrt the red dotted reference line, we will always write it as $-\theta_2$.

Then, $$arg(z_1-z_2)-arg(z_3-z_2)= \theta_1-(-\theta_2)= \theta_1+\theta_2.$$
Thus, $$arg\left(\frac{z_1-z_2}{z_3-z_2}\right)=\alpha.$$

**Thus we have the result:**  $arg\left(\frac{z_1-z_2}{z_3-z_2}\right)$ represents the angle made by the vectors joining $(z_2,z_1)$ and $(z_2,z_3)$ with $z_2$ as the vertex.
**Note, however, that the $z_2$ (that is, The complex number representing the vertex) must have the same sign in both the numerator and denominator (either both positive or both negative )**.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question occurred to me right after I posted the bounty: If we just consider the arguments, then the fractions read as: "The difference between the arguments of $z_2 - z_1$ and $z_3 - z_2$ is equal to that of the difference between $z_3 - z_1$ and $z_1 - z_2$", which means exactly that $z_2 - z_1$ and $z_3 - z_1$ are at the same angle to each other as $z_1 - z_2$ and $z_3 - z_2$.

Answer (score 0):

We can also go from modulus. If you call the lengths of the sides of the triangle, $a,b,c$, then $a^2=bc$, $b^2=ca$, $c^2=ab$.