# Find all complex $z$ such that $ 0< \arg(\frac{z-i}{z+i}) < \frac{\pi}{4} $

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The problem is: Find all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $ 0< \arg(\frac{z-i}{z+i}) < \frac{\pi}{4} $.

If $z= x+iy$, then $\operatorname{Re}(\frac{z-i}{z+i}) = \frac{x^2+y^2-1}{x^2 +(y+1)^2}$ and  $\operatorname{Im}(\frac{z-i}{z+i}) = \frac{-2x}{x^2 +(y+1)^2}$. Also, we have:
$$ 0< \frac{-2x}{x^2+y^2-1} <1$$

due to the condition from beginning.

My question is: do we also need the conditions: $\operatorname{Re}(\frac{z-i}{z+i})>0$ and $\operatorname{Im}(\frac{z-i}{z+i})>0$? I know how to plot all regions, but I'm just wondering if these two conditions are necessary. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $S=\{z=\xi+i\beta \in \mathbb C:0< Arg(z) < \frac{\pi}{4}\}$. Then $S=\{ z=\xi+i\beta \in \mathbb C:\xi>0,\beta>0,\beta<\xi\}$. Isn't it ?

Comment: If you know about Möbius (linear fractional) transformations, a more conceptual way to attack the problem is to look at the preimage of the sector $0<\mathop{\rm Arg}(w)<\frac\pi4$ under the map $z\mapsto\frac{z-i}{z+i}$; the two boundary lines must go to circles-or-lines under the inverse Möbius transformation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated by the comment of Stéphane Jaouen, a necessary and sufficient condition on $z = u + iv$ having an Argument $\theta$ in the range $0 < \theta < \dfrac{\pi}{4}$ is for the following condition to be met:

$$0 < v < u.$$

In the posted problem, you have (in effect)

$$u = \frac{x^2+y^2-1}{x^2 +(y+1)^2}, ~~v = \frac{-2x}{x^2 +(y+1)^2}. \tag2 $$

In (2) above, since the (*shared*) denominator is always positive, except for $(x,y) = (0,-1)$, you are looking
for all values of $(x,y)$ except $(0,-1)$, such that

$$0 < -2x < x^2 + y^2 - 1.$$

So, you must have that

- $x < 0$
- $0 < x^2 +2x - 1 + y^2 \implies 2 < (x+1)^2 + y^2.$

Answer (score 2):

#### Geometrical Approach:

As I have explained [in my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4473366/1062486), $\arg\left(\dfrac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}\right)$ refers to  the counterclockwise angle (measured starting from the segment represented in the denominator) made at the vertex $z$ by segments joining $z,z_1$ and $z,z_2$.

If $\arg\left(\dfrac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}\right)$ is fixed at value $\alpha$, then  the locus of $z$ is the major/minor arc of a circle with the segment joining $z_1,z_2$ as a chord, depending on whether $\alpha$ is acute/obtuse respectively, as shown:
[image]
[image]

So now you have to plot all those arcs where the chord subtends an angle less than $45^{\circ}$.
(The chord will subtend $0^\circ$ at infinity)

The circle on which the chord joining $i$ and $-i$ subtends $45^\circ$ is $(x+1)^2+y^2=2$. (Why?) So you need this region:

[image]

If you ask why the circle has its major arc towards -X and not +X, then note that the measurement of the anticlockwise angle must start from the segment joining $z$ and $-i$.

Comment: "the anticlockwise angle must start from the segment joining z and −i" : I was wrong and I couldn't understand my mistake; thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

It is very helpful, to determine the pre-image of the boundaries  first. I attack these questions this way. But, I always do mistakes when identifying the region by test points.

Pre-image of $u=v$ is the circle
$$(x+1)^2+y^2=2\tag{*}$$
that User2661923 found, the pre-image of $u$-axis is $y$-axis.

Then by choosing test points we find the solution: Left of the $y$-axis and outside of the circle $(*). $